# Does MSVC provide anything like -Wmultichar in gcc?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to have a warning when a multicharacter constant is used in MSVC? (Something similar to `-Wmultichar` in gcc). Or if there is any alternative solution to help find code like the following, please let me know.

Compiling with `W4` on this code failed to produce any warnings while with gcc I could produce `-Wmultichar` and `-Wtype-limits`:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "hello";
    if (s[0] == 'he') {}
}
```

(I'm aware of `Wall` but that produces so many warnings I didn't bother with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only in limited contexts – for the following code, there are two warnings:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char x = 'he';
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

> warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from `'int'` to `'char'`
>   warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value

These warnings could be enabled individually without enabling `/W4` or `/Wall`.

However, for the code in your question, there are no applicable warnings, even with `/Wall`.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know it isn't possible. I submitted a [feature request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2794592-add-multicharacter-warning-to-msvc).

Comment: @Jesse : Official feature requests should go to [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: If you click on "Submit Idea", it takes you to the site I linked to.

Comment: @Jesse : Ah, news to me. Sorry for the noise. :-]